# How to derive the number of on-to functions from A $\rightarrow$ B?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The number of onto functions from $A \rightarrow B$ when $a \ge b$ is:

$\sum_{j=0}^{b}$$(-1^{j})$ ${b}\choose{j}$$(b-j)^{a}$

I cannot find a derivation for this. Can someone please help?

[Not what is asked here, I am looking for a derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500674/number-of-surjective-functions-from-a-to-b)

Comment: check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500674/number-of-surjective-functions-from-a-to-b

Comment: I am looking for the derivation.

Comment: @User10101.. isn't it there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500674/number-of-surjective-functions-from-a-to-b/1302618#1302618 ?