# How many injective functions are there from $X$ to $Y$, where $X$ is infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Obviously if two sets $X$ (with cardinality $m$) and $Y$ (with cardinality $n$) are finite then the number of injective functions from $Y$ to $X$ is $n!/(n-m)!$. However, if $X$ is infinite, what is the correct answer then? I'm inclined to say that it is $n^m$, but I'm not sure how to go about proving this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your count is not correct in the finite case.

Comment: Neither is your iclination for the infinite case.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: @mk_ev112 it's still wrong.

Comment: it was a rollback error, i think it is good

Comment: It's
$$\binom{m}{n} n!$$
(_why?_), you had $n^m$...

Comment: Your $\frac{n!}{(m-n)!}$ would be $\binom{n}mm!$ if you had $n-m$ instead of $m-n$; that’s the number of injective functions from $X$ to $Y$, not $Y$ to $X$. As it stands, it’s a hybrid that doesn’t count much of anything.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott except he also has $n$ and $m$ switched in the denominator.

Comment: This might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492433/if-a-30-and-b-20-find-the-number-of-surjective-functions-fa-to-b/492441#492441

Comment: @Tobias: *sigh* A case of seeing what one expects to see.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Relate functions in $X^Y$ to injections in $(X\times Y)^Y$.