# Proving there are at least $N$ surjective functions from $A$ to $B$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$; $B = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

I have to prove that there are at least $\frac{m!}{(m-n+1)!}$ surjective functions from $A$ to $B$.

I've given it some thought, but I don't know how to work out the proof. I've looked at some [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500674/number-of-surjective-functions-from-a-to-b) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492433/if-a-30-and-b-20-find-the-number-of-surjective-functions-fa-to-b/492441#492441), but I'm not finding them helpful. Could anyone please give me a hint or tell me how I need to attack this?

I understand that there are $m!$ ways to arrange the elements of $A$, and that there are $n!$ ways to arrange the elements of $B$. I'm not sure how to draw the possible correspondences between them. I also know that the collection of all $n$-element subsets of $m$ can be expressed as ${m \choose n} = {m \choose m-n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $f:A\to B$ is a surjection. For $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ let $$g_f(k)=\min\{a\in A:f(a)=k\}\;.$$ Show that if $f$ and $h$ are surjections from $A$ to $B$, and $$\langle g_f(1),\ldots,g_f(n-1)\rangle\ne\langle g_h(1),\ldots,g_h(n-1)\rangle\;,$$ then $f\ne h$. How many possibilities are there for the $(n-1)$-tuple $\langle g_f(1),\ldots,g_f(n-1)\rangle$?

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it - could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @Newb: Can you answer the question at the end?

Comment: No. I followed up to that question. It appears to me that there are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange the tuple itself, but I'm not sure how to relate that back to $A$.

Comment: @Newb: It’s a sequence of $n-1$ distinct objects chosen from the set $A$, which has altogether $m$ members. How many ways are there to choose such a sequence? This is one of the basic counting tasks.

Comment: Sure, that's ${m \choose n-1} = {m \choose m-n+1} = \frac{m!}{(m-n+1)!(n-1)!}$ But how do I show that $\frac{m!}{(m-n+1)!(n-1)!} \geq \frac{m!}{(m-n+1)!}$?

Comment: @Newb: No, it isn’t $\binom{m}{n-1}$: that’s the number of $(m-1)$-element **subsets** of $A$, and we want the number of $(m-1)$-term **sequences** of distinct elements of $A$ (which is a quantity that actually appears somewhere in your last comment).

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with choosing $x$-term sequences from a set. How do I go about doing that?

edit: Hold on - there are $m$ choices for the first element, $m-1$ for the second, etc. So it's like a factorial, but I have to stop it at some $m-x$?

Comment: @Newb: No, not $(m-1)!$: there are only $n-1$ of them, so the numbers of choices range from $m-0=m$ down to $m-(n-2)=m-n+2$. Alternatively, you can think of it as choosing a set of $n-1$ things, which can be done in $\binom{m}{n-1}$ ways, and then arranging them in a particular order, which can be done in $(n-1)!$ ways.

Comment: Got it. Finally. Sorry for needing the careful walk-through. Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Newb: You’re very welcome. Even if it takes a while, I like it better when you make the final step yourself.