# How many surjective functions are there.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How many surjective functions exist from the set $A= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (Domain) to the set $B=\{w,x,y,z\}$ (Image).

I have no idea on how you do this. Any hints would be helpful.

I know that I can begin with $4^6$ functions and exclude the non surjective ones, but I don't know how you do this.

Comment: These are called Stirling numbers of the second kind...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: I didn't learn stirling numbers...

Comment: Or of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492433/if-a-30-and-b-20-find-the-number-of-surjective-functions-fa-to-b

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by inclusion-exclusion rather than Stirling numbers of the second kind then you will get $${4 \choose 4}\times 4^6 - {4 \choose 3}\times 3^6 + {4 \choose 2}\times  2^6 -{4 \choose 1}\times 1^6 +{4 \choose 0}\times 0^6.$$

Comment: What formula did you use ?

Comment: @Astroman: [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Clearly $4^6$ counts some functions which are not surjective since they send $A$ to subsets of $B$ with three or fewer elements.   So subtract off $3^6$ four times as there are four subsets of $B$ with three elements.  But you have taken off the functions which send $A$ to subsets of $B$ with two or fewer elements too often, so add back $2^6$ six times as there are six subsets of $B$ with two elements. Then deal  subsets of $B$ with one or zero elements in the same way...

Comment: But did you begin your sum at k=0 to 3 and substracted this sum from $4^6$

Comment: @Astroman: I began my calculation at $4^6$